# Interactive / Reactive change of min / max values of sliderInput

Tags: r, shiny

I've found [some information](https://github.com/wch/testapp/tree/master/setinput) about how to change the `value` of a `sliderInput` with a reactive expression within the `siderbarPanel`. But instead of the `value`, I'd like to change `min` and `max` of the slider with a `numericInput`. In [this](https://github.com/wch/testapp/blob/master/setinput/server.R) script for `server.R` it says that only `label` and `value` can be changed for sliders. Is there any other possibility to change the min/max values of `sliderInput` with a reactive expression?

Here's an exmple:

ui.R:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  
  #Sidebar with controls to select the variable to plot
  sidebarPanel(
   
  #Numeric Inputs
    numericInput("min_val", "Enter Minimum Value", 1993),
    
    numericInput("max_val", "Enter Maximum Value", 2013),

  #Slider 
    sliderInput("inSlider", "Slider", 
                min=1993, max=2013, value=2000),

# Now I would like to change min and max from sliderInput
# by changing the numericInput.

  mainPanel()
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  reactive({
    x<-input$min_val
    y<-input$max_val
    updateSliderInput(session, "inSlider", min=x, max=y, value=x)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this is best accomplished by using shiny's dynamic UI functions via `renderUI()` and `uiOutput()`. Try out the following example:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Test Shiny App"),

  sidebarPanel(
    #Numeric Inputs
    numericInput("min_val", "Enter Minimum Value", 1993),
    numericInput("max_val", "Enter Maximum Value", 2013),
    #display dynamic UI
    uiOutput("slider")
  ),

  mainPanel()
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  #make dynamic slider
  output$slider <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("inSlider", "Slider", min=input$min_val, max=input$max_val, value=2000)
  })

})
```

Comment: Thanks @David , the sliders work! But I have problems to get an output value from the slider. I tried `input$slider`, but it seems that `slider` doesn't give back any values. Any ideas?

Comment: Just realised that I have to use  `input$inSlider `. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: I often write this way uiOutput("outputSlider") and sliderInput("inputSlider", etc.) to avoid the confusion...

Comment: I think this is depreciated now.

Comment: @scottyaz what is the alternative?