# reactive change min/max range + 2 dataframes Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have one problem with my Shiny app. Firstly, I have two `dataframes` in which there are two `numeric` columns ( `number` and `number2`). I also have dynamic ui `sliderInput`. Shiny app works fine till... when I choose `Item` dataframe, choose `number` in `Y-axis variable` and set `range` in `sliderInput` between e.g. 15 and 18, and after that I want to change `Y-axis variable` to `number2` I get an error: 
 `Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : wrong result size (2), expected 0 or 1`

 I know that the problem is caused because number in `number2` column is between 1 and 10 and previous settings does not included that numbers. Could anyone tell me how to improve it?

**ui.R**

```
library(ggvis)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel(""),

sidebarLayout(
 sidebarPanel(
  radioButtons("dataset", label = h4("Choose dataframe"),
               choices = list("Item" = "df1", "Task" = "df2")),
   selectInput("yvar", "Y-axis variable", axis_vars_y, selected = "number"),
   uiOutput("slider")
   ),
mainPanel(
  ggvisOutput("plot")
  )
 )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(lazyeval)

df1_number <-sample(seq(1,20,0.01),20,replace = T)
df2_number <-sample(seq(1,20,0.01),20,replace = T)
df1_number2 <-sample(seq(1,10,0.01),20,replace = T)
df2_number2 <-sample(seq(1,10,0.01),20,replace = T)

df1 <- data.frame(name = rep(letters[1:4],each = 5), number = df1_number, number2 = df1_number2)
df2 <- data.frame(name = rep(letters[1:4],each = 5), number = df2_number, number2 = df2_number2)
axis_vars_y <- c("number" = "number", "number2" = "number2")



shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           df1 = df1,
           df2 = df2)
  })

  axis_vara_y <- reactive({
    switch(input$yvar,
           number = 2,
           number2 = 3)
  }) 

    output$slider <- renderUI({
      sliderInput("inslider","Slider", min   = min(datasetInput()[,axis_vara_y()]), 
                                       max   = max(datasetInput()[,axis_vara_y()]),
                                       value = c(min(datasetInput()[,axis_vara_y()]), 
                                                 max(datasetInput()[,axis_vara_y()])),
                                       step = 0.5)
})

  data <- reactive({
    filteredData <- datasetInput()
    if(!is.null(input$inslider)){
      filteredData <- filteredData %>%
        filter(filteredData[,axis_vara_y()] >= input$inslider[1],
               filteredData[,axis_vara_y()] <= input$inslider[2])
    }
    filteredData
})

  data_two <- reactive({
    data() %>%
      mutate(id = 1:n())

  })  

  vis <- reactive({

    yvar_name <- names(axis_vars_y)[axis_vars_y == input$yvar]
    yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$yvar))

    data_two %>%
      ggvis(x = ~name, y = yvar) %>%    
      layer_points(size := 120,
                     fill = ~name,
                     fillOpacity := 0.6, 
                     key := ~id)

      })
      vis %>% bind_shiny("plot")
    })
```

**Update**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The same `error` occurs when I set a range which does not included any value from `number` column (e.g. between 13 and 14).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you realize, you are getting the error because the filtered dataset has no rows.  A simple workaround would be to return the full dataset.  This will reset the `inputSlider` for you to continue working without error.  You only need to change your reactive `data` function.

```
data <- reactive({
  filteredData <- datasetInput()
  axisData <- axis_vara_y()

  if(!is.null(input$inslider)){
    filteredData <- filteredData %>%
      filter(filteredData[,axisData] >= input$inslider[1],
             filteredData[,axisData] <= input$inslider[2])
  }

  # the new part to reset the slider
  if(nrow(filteredData) == 0){
    return(datasetInput())
  }else{
    return(filteredData)
  }
})
```

I have taken the liberty of simplifying the code a little bit as you can assign your reactive data statements and not have the shiny app call them several times.

Comment: Tkanks a lot ! I struggled with it for a long time!:)

Comment: @Nicolabo, glad to help.  If this solves your problem please remember to accept the answer :)

Comment: What about use `navbarPage` in ggvis. Is it possible ( I describe my problem here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474903/navbar-page-and-wrong-update-of-ggvis-plot-shiny