# navbar Page and wrong update of ggvis plot Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

Hi
I just create Shiny app. But there is a little problem when I want to present my Shiny app in `navbarPage` way. I mean, when I add new `navbarPage` named `Introduction` everithing works fine with plot till... I come back to Introduction `navbarPage` and then one again come back to Plot `navbarPage`, plot does not work well. What happended? How to fix it?

**ui.R**

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

shinyUI(
  navbarPage("",
             tabPanel("Introduction",
                      fluidRow(
                        column(3,
                               wellPanel(
                               )

                        ),

                        column(9,
                               br(),br(),br(),
                               h5("This screen will soon display a brief introduction to the project.")
                        ) 
                      )
             ),     
             tabPanel("Plot",
                      fluidRow(
                        column(3,
                          radioButtons("dataset", label = h4("Choose dataframe"),
                                       choices = list("Item" = "df1", "Task" = "df2")),
                          selectInput("yvar", "Y-axis variable", axis_vars_y, selected = "number"),
                          uiOutput("slider")

                          ),
                    column(9,
                          ggvisOutput("plot")
        )
    )
  )
)
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(lazyeval)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           df1 = df1,
           df2 = df2)
  })

  axis_vara_y <- reactive({
    switch(input$yvar,
           number = 2,
           number2 = 3)
  }) 

    output$slider <- renderUI({
      sliderInput("inslider","Slider", min   = round(min(datasetInput()[,axis_vara_y()]),0)-1, 
                                       max   = round(max(datasetInput()[,axis_vara_y()]),0)+1,
                                       value = c(round(min(datasetInput()[,axis_vara_y()]),0)-1, 
                                                 round(max(datasetInput()[,axis_vara_y()]),0)+1),
                                       step = 0.5)
})

data <- reactive({
  filteredData <- datasetInput()
  axisData <- axis_vara_y()

  if(!is.null(input$inslider)){
    filteredData <- filteredData %>%
      filter(filteredData[,axisData] >= input$inslider[1],
             filteredData[,axisData] <= input$inslider[2])
  }

  if (nrow(filteredData) == 0){
    return (datasetInput())
  }else{
    return(filteredData)
  }
})
  data_two <- reactive({
    data() %>%
      mutate(id = 1:n())

  })  

  vis <- reactive({

    yvar_name <- names(axis_vars_y)[axis_vars_y == input$yvar]
    yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$yvar))

    data_two %>%
      ggvis(x = ~name, y = yvar) %>%    
      layer_points(size := 120,
                 fill = ~name,
                 fillOpacity := 0.6)

  })
  vis %>% bind_shiny("plot")
})
```

**global.R**

```
df1_number <-sample(seq(1,20,0.01),20,replace = T)
df2_number <-sample(seq(1,20,0.01),20,replace = T)
df1_number2 <-sample(seq(1,5,0.01),20,replace = T)
df2_number2 <-sample(seq(1,5,0.01),20,replace = T)

df1 <- data.frame(name = rep(letters[1:4],each = 5), number = df1_number, number2 = df1_number2)
df2 <- data.frame(name = rep(letters[1:4],each = 5), number = df2_number, number2 = df2_number2)
axis_vars_y <- c("number" = "number", "number2" = "number2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never had much luck putting ggvis inside of a reactive. Weird things happen like what you experienced. Try [this](https://gist.github.com/corynissen/9cdf1275f394e7945eb6).

```
shiny::runGist("https://gist.github.com/corynissen/9cdf1275f394e7945eb6")
```

You have to assign the y value in the data_two reactive, then run the ggvis outside of the reactive().

Comment: You are correct to assign the y value to data_two but you can still make the `ggvis` reactive.  It works fine once you add the y value as you demonstrate.  The difference is whether you want only the data replotted or the other aspects (e.g. title) as well.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011544/how-is-data-passed-from-reactive-shiny-expression-to-ggvis-plot/25060999#25060999) for a good explanation between reactive or non-reactive ggvis objects.

Comment: @ cdeterman @cory OK, thanks but this solution solve the problem partly. I mean try this scenario: `Introduction Panel` -> `Plot Panel` -> change to Task `dataframe` -> change `Y-axis variable` to `number2` -> come back to  `Introduction Panel` -> go to `Plot Panel` once again -> change `Y-axis variable` to `number`. As a result , plot loses all `a` and `b` dot points and show only some `c` and `d` dot points. Is it possible to improve it?

Comment: Try my gist again. I used @cdeterman's advice and tried the ggvis inside the reactive. It's a little clunkier in the browser (reloads entire plot on yvar change), but points don't randomly disappear. I replace data_two() and the ggvis with one reactive for data and plot

Comment: @ cory Thanks!, I see difference.. in that case I think Shiny must be developed to manage with build in transition animations of ggvis , I hope it may possible one day!